# docker as service parameter

Tags: service, docker

I need to configure docker as service in my CentOs machine.

It's set up and works fine. However I need to add this host `-H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`.

How can I set this parameter up in order to each time the service is started this option is reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docker daemon configuration page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/configuring/#/configuring-docker-1), those options should go in a `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf` config file.

For instance:

> Override the ExecStart configuration from your `docker.conf` file to customize the docker daemon.
>   **To modify the ExecStart configuration you have to specify an empty configuration followed by a new one as follows**:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -D --tls=true --tlscert=/var/docker/server.pem --tlskey=/var/docker/serverkey.pem -H tcp://192.168.59.3:2376
```